# DataGridView Changing AutoSizeRowsMode Throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

If a dgv is currently has `AutoSizeRowsMode = DisplayedCells`, then setting to `None` causes an exception.

Below is the code to reproduce the issue. To cause the exception to occur, simply click on one of the column headers. The exception will happen even if some of the rows are visible. However, if the `Form` is resized large enough then the exception stops happening. Tested using `.NET35` `.NET40` and `.NET45.`

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    Button btn = new Button { Text = "Button" };

    public MyForm() {
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells; // <---- this is required to cause the exception
        dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(SystemFonts.MenuFont.FontFamily, 14f, FontStyle.Bold);

        // The underlying data source doesn't matter, exception happens in both cases
        //dgv.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
        //dgv.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2");
        //dgv.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column3");

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column1");
        table.Columns.Add("Column2");
        table.Columns.Add("Column3");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            table.Rows.Add(i, i, i);
            //dgv.Rows.Add(i, i, i);
        }
        dgv.DataSource = table;
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Controls.Add(dgv);
        f.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 90); // just enough so only the headers are visible
        f.Show();

        dgv.MouseDown += dgv_MouseDown;
    }

    void dgv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView) sender;

        // using reflection, the Exception occurs on rowIndex == 1
        //int index = 0;
        //Type ty = typeof(DataGridViewRow);
        //var pi = ty.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(p => p.Name == "ThicknessInternal").FirstOrDefault();
        //var pi2 = ty.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(p => p.Name == "CachedThickness").FirstOrDefault();
        //for (index = dgv.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible); index != -1; index =  dgv.Rows.GetNextRow(index, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)) {
        //  DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows.SharedRow(index);
        //  object val1 = pi.GetValue(dataGridViewRow);
        //  object val2 = pi.GetValue(dataGridViewRow);
        //  pi.SetValue(dataGridViewRow, val2);
        //}

        dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None; // <------- Exception here
    }

}
```

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.GetRowState(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowGlobalAutoSize(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RestoreRowsCachedThickness()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnAutoSizeRowsModeChanged(DataGridViewAutoSizeModeEventArgs e)
   at Program.MyForm.dgv_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) in c:\temp\...\Program.cs:line 2483
```

Looking at the source code for `DataGridView` on `MSDN`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,237455f3980aebd9

The `RestoreRowsCachedThickness` loops through each row and sets: `dataGridViewRow.ThicknessInternal = dataGridViewRow.CachedThickness;`

The `DataGridViewBand.ThicknessInternal` property doesn't check to see if the values are actually different, it always fires the `OnBandThicknessChanged` event.

That triggers an event which calls a couple of other methods, eventually getting to the line:

```
    private void OnRowGlobalAutoSize(int rowIndex)
    {
        DataGridViewElementStates rowState = this.Rows.GetRowState(rowIndex);
//...
    }
```

It is strange that the `RowCollection` is throwing an index out of bounds exception.

Is there a sensible way to handle this exception (bug?) besides wrapping it in a `try-catch` statement?

Comment: ok, got the error, but why would you want to code it that way?  That's an odd time to want to change that property.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for confirming. The columns are set to `AutoSize`. However, the dgv allows the user to resize a specific column by clicking and dragging between two column headers. For better responsiveness, the rows are set auto-size `None`, otherwise it is laggy as the column is resized. So the above code is a very stripped down version of the resize column logic.

Comment: Did You solve this? I have the exact same issue right now and I'm pulling my hair out :/

Comment: @Misiu Ended up wrapping the `dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;` in a `try-catch`.

Comment: @Misiu I added an answer to prevent the exception.

Comment: I'm checking Your solution right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Call `LoopThroughRows(dgv)` before setting the `AutoSizeRowsMode` property. The `DataGridView` doesn't create rows if it doesn't has to. Looping through the rows forces the creation of each row and prevents the exception.

Possibly in `Release` mode the code might be removed by the optimizer, hence the attributes.

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization | System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void LoopThroughRows(DataGridView dgv) {
    DataGridViewRowCollection rows = dgv.Rows;
    for (int i = rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        DataGridViewRow row = rows[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The default behavior (the one that throws the error) is a bug in my opinion.
Now that WinForms is open-source (https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) maybe this should be reported as a bug? Could You fill an issue describing this problem?